# How to implements secure connections (No | SSL | STARTTLS) in SmtpClient to send mail?

Tags: c#, ssl, smtpclient

I use class SmtpClient of namespace System.Net.Mail to send mail:
I create SmtpClient to send mail:

```
private static SmtpClient CreateSmtpClient (string host, string user, string password, int port)
        {
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient (host, port);
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (user, password);
            return smtpClient;
        }
```

and use it:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage ();
var smtpClient = CreateSmtpClient (host, user, password, port);
smtpClient.Send (mailMessage);
```

How to implements secure email transfer when I have 3 option secure connection is: No | STARTTLS | SSL ?
Many thanks !

Comment: For STARTTLS just do `smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: @Evk Thank for your reply. So SSL ? Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: If by SSL you mean connecting to 465 port (by default) - then it's not supported by SmtpClient.

Comment: @Evk, I got it. Thank for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET built-in mail class doesn't support the needed SSL method (implicit SSL) and there's nothing to do with this: the reason is explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465/).

There exist third-party SMTP client components that do both explicit and implicit SSL , for example, AIM(Aegis Implicit Mail), or you should consider sending email through Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook, etc.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Maybe I will choose an exist third-party SMTP client components.

Comment: @maxchiu, how did you come accross microsoft dev blog in your search ? It's a very sound information.